# Setting mapred.child.java.opts in Hive script results in MR job getting 'killed' right away

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have been having a few jobs failing due to OutOfMemory and GC overhead limit exceeded errors. To counter the former I tried setting `SET mapred.child.java.opts="-Xmx3G";` at the start of the hive script**.

Basically any time I add this option to the script, the MR jobs that get scheduled(for the first of several queries in the script) are 'killed' right away.

Any thoughts on how to rectify this? Are there any other params that need to be tinkered with in conjunction with max heap space(eg. `io.sort.mb`)? Any help would be **most appreciated**.

FWIW, I am using `hive-0.7.0` with `hadoop-0.20.2`. The default setting for max heap size in our cluster is 1200M.

TIA.

** - Some other alternatives that were tried(with comical effect but no discernible change in outcome):

- `SET mapred.child.java.opts="-Xmx3G";`
- `SET mapred.child.java.opts="-server -Xmx3072M";`
- `SET mapred.map.child.java.opts ="-server -Xmx3072M";`

  `SET mapred.reduce.child.java.opts ="-server -Xmx3072M";`
- `SET mapred.child.java.opts="-Xmx2G";`

Update 1: It is possible that it's not necessarily anything to do with setting heap size. Tinkering with mapred.child.java.opts in any way is causing the same outcome. For example setting it thusly, `SET mapred.child.java.opts="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC";` is having the same result of MR jobs getting killed right away. Or even setting it explicitly in the script to what is the 'cluster default' causes this.

Update 2: Added a pastebin of a `grep` of JobTracker logs [here](http://pastebin.com/wVrqZHuc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Figured this would end up being something trivial/inane and it was in the end.

Setting `mapred.child.java.opts` thusly:

`SET mapred.child.java.opts="-Xmx4G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC";`

is unacceptable. But this seem to go through fine:

`SET mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx4G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC;` (minus the double-quotes)

*sigh*. Having better debug options/error messages would have been nice.

Answer (score 1):

Two other guards can restrict task memory usage.  Both are designed for admins to enforce QoS, so if you're not one of the admins on the cluster, you may be unable to change them.

The first is the ulimit, which can be set directly in the node OS, or by setting [`mapred.child.ulimit`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html#mapred.child.ulimit).

The second is a pair of cluster-wide [`mapred.cluster.max.*.memory.mb`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html#mapred.cluster.map.memory.mb) properties that enforce memory usage by comparing job settings `mapred.job.map.memory.mb` and `mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb` against those cluster-wide limits.

Comment: I am beginning to think that this doesn't even have anything to do with the heap size setting. Tinkering with `mapred.child.java.opts` in any way is causing the same outcome. For example setting it thusly, `SET mapred.child.java.opts="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC";` is having the same result of MR jobs getting killed right away. Or even setting it explicitly in the script to what is the 'cluster default'  causes this.

Comment: Hmm, are you able to access job tracker logs?  There may be more failure details there.

Comment: I have been trying to trawl through them. The only clues I see there are attempts to schedule tasks that are data-local. I don't see any task tracker logs 'cuz: a) Job tracker logs only seem to report that certain nodes have 'splits'. However it doesn't report scheduling any tasks. b) Checking for 'attempt' logs on all TT nodes(that are listed as having splits) yields nothing. I have a feeling that there is some Hive voodoo going on - even before the query execution begins, especially since the jobs are getting 'killed' and not necessarily 'failing'. However I don't see anything in `hive.log`.

Comment: Added a pastebin of a `grep` of JobTracker logs [here](http://pastebin.com/wVrqZHuc).

Comment: It seems like the job tracker does try to start those tasks, so there might also be some relevant logs on corresponding task tracker nodes.

Comment: Do you also run a task tracker on the jobtracker node?

Comment: > Do you also run a task tracker on the jobtracker node?

Nope.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas (I don't have an access to a live cluster right now to experiment with locally), but even if this is Hive related, there should be some evidence of a failure on the task level, because it's still going through MapRed.  If you're not able to pinpoint the exact nodes the tasks were attempted on, I can suggest trying to analyse the job run through the web UI, which might be available on your cluster.  You can try going to http://[jobtracker_hostname]:50030

Comment: Looks like it was just the use of double quotes in setting the value of the option that was causing the issue. *sigh*. Details in the answer I added. Thanks for your assistance, btw. Much appreciated.